# interceptUrlMap being overridden?

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm working on a rather large web app that uses Grails and we are trying to implement the use of role security.  When the system was set up, grails was basically granting full role access to CAS authenticated users, but when I created specific roles for each controller method, it just completely ignored the roles and continued allowing full access to authenticated users.

Here's what I'm doing in Config.groovy:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.securityConfigType = SecurityConfigType.InterceptUrlMap
grails.plugins.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
    "/controllerName/create":                       [ "hasRole( 'ROLE_CREATE' )" ],
    "/controllerName/remove":                       [ "hasRole( 'ROLE_DELETE' )" ],
    "/controllerName/listEntries":                  [ "hasRole( 'ROLE_VIEW' )" ],
    "/controllerName/listAllEntries":               [ "hasRole( 'ROLE_VIEW' )" ],
    "/controllerName/getDefaultCategories":         [ "hasRole( 'ROLE_VIEW' )" ]
]
```

The UrlConfig.goovy doesn't have an entry for controllerName.

When the create, remove, or other services in controllerName are called by the application, it doesn't matter if the user has the specified role or not.  It just acts like there is no mapping there.

Is it possible that some other setting is overriding the interceptUrlMap?  If so, where should I start to look?

I should mention that we have to use Grails 1.3.8

Update:  I tried the lower case thing mentioned below and it still failed.  However, if I just did a top level ("/controllername/**") controller entry (as opposed to specifying an action within the controller, it restricted access.  Unfortunately, we want to do "/controllername/create" type security.  Any thoughts?

Comment: "it doesn't matter if the user has the specified role or not. It just acts like there is no mapping there" - I'm sorry, but exactly what happenned? You get a 404 or you can't access the page by 403 error?

Comment: The method functions normally.  No errors.

Answer (score 2):

URLs must be lowercase, there should be a warning about that at startup. Change "controllerName" to "controllername", "listAllEntries" to "listallentries", etc.

Comment: Burt, is this true in Grails 2.0 with Spring Security Core 1.2.7.3? I have camel-case in my interceptUrlMap and I don't seem to be having any problems..

Comment: According to this page [http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/single.html](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/single.html), it is still a valid requirement for Config.groovy.

I'll try it now...

Comment: Update:  I tried the lower case thing and it still failed.  However, if I just did a top level ("/controllername/**") controller entry (as opposed to specifying an action within the controller, it restricted access.  Unfortunately, we want to do "/controllername/create" type security.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Burt, Can we allow wildcards to the interceptUrlMap ? Here is my question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21792043/allowing-a-method-to-be-public-using-interceptmap-in-grails-spring-security-plug

Answer (score 0):

It has to be like this, here is my example: 
please note that *** mean all the action inside that controller

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
   '/secure/create':    ['ROLE_ADMIN'],
   '/finance/***':   ['ROLE_FINANCE', 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY'],
   '/js/**':        ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
   '/css/**':       ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
   '/images/**':    ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
   '/*':            ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
   '/login/**':     ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
   '/logout/**':    ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY']
]
```

Comment: When you say "please note that [asterisk] mean[s] all the action" did you mean to type three (3) asterisks? (like you show in the /finance/*** example)?