# Allowing a method to be public using interceptMap in Grails Spring Security plugin

Tags: grails, spring-security, authorization

How can I open up a method of a controller to public using interceptMap with Grails Spring Security Plugin ?

I have a url like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/testapp/user/showIdentity?token=2&userID=b18cac92f0636da8fcd464d5b595b9aba86b5f11
```

So in my interceptMap I have:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
    '/':                  ['permitAll'],
    '/index':             ['permitAll'],
    '/index.gsp':         ['permitAll'],
    '/**/js/**':          ['permitAll'],
    '/**/css/**':         ['permitAll'],
    '/**/images/**':      ['permitAll'],
    '/**/favicon.ico':    ['permitAll'],
    '/login/**':          ['permitAll'],
    '/logout/**':         ['permitAll'],        
    '/**':         ['ROLE_ADMIN']   
    ]
```

What is the way to allow "showIdentity" method of the controller as permitAll and the rest of the controller methods as ROLE_ADMIN which is the controller's default ?

I know with Spring Security ACL Plugin we can do more stuff, but I was wondering if I could use Spring Security Plugin and just do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding these two should do it:

```
'/user/showIdentity':   ['permitAll'],
'/user/showIdentity.*': ['permitAll'],
```

The 2nd one is needed for requests like `/user/showIdentity.xml`. Other `/user/**` requests will be matched by the `/**` rule.

Comment: Thanks Burt. Worked great! :)

Comment: Burt can you please take a look at this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23367370/implementing-follower-list-efficiently-with-grails-and-gorm